# WebStorm 2018.1: I am not able to hit breakpoints running remote debugging typescript from docker container

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, webstorm

I am using the docker integration tool to run docker-compose to start two containers, one for node and one for mongodb.

Here is the docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2.1'
services:
 mongo:
    container_name: "app_mongo"
    hostname: "mongo"
    tty: true
    image: mongo:latest
    environment:
      - MONGO_DATA_DIR=/data/db
      - MONGO_LOG_DIR=/dev/null
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=***********
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=************
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=********************
    volumes:
      - /data/db:/data/db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    command: "mongod --smallfiles --auth"
    networks:
      - my-app-network
 group:
     container_name: "app_api1"
     hostname: "api1"
     build:
       context: .
       dockerfile: api1.dev.yml
     entrypoint: ["npm", "run", "debug"]
     volumes:
       - ".:/home/app"
     ports:
       - 3000:3000
       - 56745:56745
     depends_on:
       - "mongo"
     networks:
       - my-app-network
networks:
    my-app-network:
       driver: bridge
```

Here is the api1.dev.yml file:

```
FROM node:latest

ADD package.json /tmp/package.json
RUN cd /tmp && npm install --production && npm install -g nodemon
RUN mkdir -p /home/app && cp -a /tmp/node_modules /home/app/ && mkdir -p /home/app/dist

ADD package.json /home/app/package.json
ADD .env /home/app/.env
WORKDIR /home/app
```

Here is the script entry in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
  "debug": "nodemon --inspect=56745 --require ts-node/register app/app.ts"
  // "debug": "nodemon -L --inspect=56745 dist/myapp/app.js"
}
```

I also added a new "Attach to Node.js/Chrome" item to attach to the debugging port for node.

I run the docker-compose file followed by debugging the "Attach to Node.js/Chrome" item after node is up and listening.

When I try to hit a breakpoint in a .ts file, nothing is happening.  I am seeing the endpoint is called.

What are the steps involved in debugging a typescript app from docker and what am I doing wrong?

Where can I find a good tutorial that walks through how to debug typecript for a node.js app hosted inside of a docker container?

Comment: but can you connect from `chrome://inspect`? Maybe it's not webstorm issue really

Comment: also you probably need to use `EXPOSE` in your dockerfile

Comment: In what way would I use EXPOSE?

Comment: Is there a recommended tutorial that I can use to set this up?  So far I had to pull from several different tutorials.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know if there are descent tutorials, but you could look up EXPOSE in docker file reference. EXPOSE 3000 56745 would open these ports for external connections, otherwise "ports" does nothing. Then just connect with chrome://inspect, but keep in mind you have to find out the IP address of your docker network.   172 something something.  Only After this works would 
I recommend trying webstorm connection

Comment: If I am using expose, could I still run entrypoint as opposed to CMD in the dockerfile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An answer was finally provided to me.  Ultimately, I had to change the debug script from "debug": "nodemon -L --inspect=56745 dist/myapp/app.js" to "nodemon -L --inspect=0.0.0.0:56745 dist/myapp/app.js".